# R: Test condition on column of dataframe elements within list; return smaller list

Tags: r, list, function, split, dataframe

My goal is take a list of dataframes, see if a specific column of the data frames has a max value of 0, and if so, remove that data frame from my list.

Right now I am looping over names of the list.  Given that this is R, there must be a better way. I feel I need some function applied through `lapply()` to get this right.  I've also considered `ddply()` but I think that maybe overkill.  Here is what I have so far:

```
# Make df of First element
myColumn <- rep ("ElementA",times=10)
values <- seq(1,10)
a <- data.frame(myColumn,values)
# Make df of second element
myColumn <- rep ("ElementB",times=10)
values <- rep(0,10)
b <- data.frame(myColumn,values)

# Bind the dataframes together
df <- rbind(a,b)

#Now split the dataframes based on element name
myList <- split(df,df$myColumn)

# Now loop through element lists and check for max of 0 in values
for (name in names(myList)) { # Loop through List  
  if (max(myList[[name]]$values) == 0) { # Check Max for 0
      myList <- myList[[-names]] # If 0, remove element from list
  } # Close If
} # Close Loop

Error in -names : invalid argument to unary operator
```

I've tested my code outside the loop, and it all seems to work.
Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: do you  have the same columns in all dataframes?

Comment: Yes. The same column is in all dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
myList <- myList[sapply(myList, function(d) max(d$values) != 0)]
```

instead of the `for()` loop. This will let pass dataframes with zero rows, with a warning.

To ensure empty dataframes are removed, use this:

```
myList <- myList[sapply(myList, function(d) if(nrow(d)==0) FALSE else max(d$values)!=0)]
```

Comment: To give you an idea of alternative solutions, using `base` R, `plyr` as well as `data.table`, you can have a look at several very nice answers to my similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764339/subset-a-list-a-plyr-way,

Comment: Henrik - thanks so much for your comment.  Your post did provide helpful code and brings me one step closer to what I really want (but did not ask for above).  The following code gives a dataframe without those list element dataframes that do not meet my test condition.  `shortDf <- ddply(df,"myColumn", subset, max(values) > 0)`